# Materialize navbar / buttons not responsive

Tags: html, button, navbar, materialize, responsive

Whenever I try to re-size my window, the navbar doesn't seem to be responsive.  Instead, the components go to the next line.  How do I make it so that the navbar gets bigger / smaller so that it can accommodate all of the content when resized?

ex: https://jsfiddle.net/pv860zh0/ the 'rider alerts' and 'translate - english' buttons go to the next line.  If you resize further the other categories also go to the next line.

```
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="ridingdd">Riding TheBus<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="programsdd">Programs<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="csdd">Customer Service<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="visitorsdd">Visitors<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="aboutdd">About<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
  <li>  <a class='dropdown-button btn red darken-3' href='#' data-activates='radd'>Rider Alerts</a></li>
  <li>  <a class='dropdown-button btn blue darken-3' href='#' data-activates='tdd'>Translate - English</a></li>
```

Maybe it might be from the buttons?  If so how would I make those buttons responsive?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in materialize [documentation](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!):

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse">
      <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
      <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
      <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Also, include in your jquery `document.ready()`:

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

This will create a navbar with regular menu on medium sized screens and larger, and a collapsed menu on the smaller sized screens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This method worked except now I the buttons seem to be overlapping onto other divs whenever I resize the page, for example, http://prntscr.com/b9cxth
Do you know how to fix this part?

Comment: Could you post the html?

Comment: I think this could also be solved with having the side div go to the next line...but how would I do that?

Comment: Add `display: block;` to the overflowing button. Also, better to have each element on it's own row. i.e. `col s12 m6` (half a row on medium+ screens, and full row on small screens)

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions worked! However, now, for the button, the text still overflows to the other div (ex. prntscr.com/ba0n6y). Is there any way to get it to make the button resize (get bigger/smaller)?